Dbeaver JDBC Exceptions
this is my first time using stack overflow so please bear with me. I don't have much experience working with SQL let alone postgresql and the DBeaver IDE. I'm faced with the following error when trying to run a simple query.
SQL Error [57P03]: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
Error position:
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL Error [57P03]: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:209)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:1)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.DBUtils.createStatement(DBUtils.java:1436)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.DBUtils.makeStatement(DBUtils.java:1403)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:590)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$2(SQLQueryJob.java:505)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:191)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:524)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:976)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:4133)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:191)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5148)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:114)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:397)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:305)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCConnectionOpener.run(JDBCConnectionOpener.java:109)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCConnectionOpener.run(JDBCConnectionOpener.java:83)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:221)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.PostgreDataSource.openConnection(PostgreDataSource.java:558)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:106)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:91)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.getConnection(JDBCExecutionContext.java:204)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.getOriginal(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:60)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:100)
My programs were running fine not too long ago until I faced an error I couldn't diagnose so I tried to re-install everything(postgresql and dbeaver). Seems this did not work as I keep facing errors with my databases. These errors are keeping me from completing coursework so I'm eager to find a solution as soon as possible. Not sure where to proceed from here.

FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode, your database server has crashed and is now recovering. You just have to wait until it's ready. Check your database logfiles as well.
